# Ошибка Unknown column 't.entry_id' in 'on clause'

Tags: mysql

Подскажите пожалуйста, что не так с кодом?

> Получаю ошибку: Unknown column 't.entry_id' in 'on clause'

Я так понимаю проблема в строке
`LEFT JOIN exp_category_posts ON t.entry_id = exp_category_posts.entry_id`

Вот полный запрос.

```
SELECT t.entry_id AS entry_id
       , t.title AS title
       , t.weblog_id, t.url_title AS url_title
       , t.entry_date AS entry_date,COUNT(*)
FROM exp_weblog_titles AS t
     ,(select title
               ,entry_date
               ,entry_id 
       from exp_weblog_titles 
       where weblog_id=3
     ) as newsreal
LEFT JOIN exp_category_posts ON t.entry_id = exp_category_posts.entry_id
WHERE newsreal.title LIKE CONCAT('%', t.title, '%') 
      AND t.site_id IN ('1') 
      AND t.status = 'open' 
      AND t.weblog_id = 13 
      AND newsreal.entry_date > UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 3600*24*7 
      AND exp_category_posts.cat_id = 59
GROUP BY title
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 20
```

Comment: Ну чудес не бывает, так что в exp_weblog_titles нет колонки entry_id

Comment: Есть, в том то и дело. Без LEFT JOIN все работает. Но нужно подцепить категорию.

Comment: Значит поменяйте местами подзапрос и таблицу `t` что бы left join действительно разделял таблицы, которые в on (хотя это и странно)

Comment: Спасибо, все заработало :)

Answer (score 1):

*Ответ из комментариев от [Mike](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/194569/mike)*

Поменяйте местами подзапрос и таблицу `t` что бы `LEFT JOIN` действительно разделял таблицы, которые в конструкции `ON`.